# Mysql SELECT command

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
    $sn=$_GET['sn'];
    $query="SELECT * FROM `banner_ad` WHERE `banner_no`='$sn'";
    if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
    {
        $num=mysql_num_rows($query_run);
        if($num == 1)
        {
            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($query_run))
            {
                $banner_name=$rows['banner_name'];
                //$banner_site_url=$rows['Banner_website_url'];
                $banner_image_url=$rows['banner_image_url'];
            }
        } else {
            echo'<font color="red"> There is two entry for this same serial number.</font>';
            }

    } else {
        echo'<font color="red"> Query does not run.</font>';
        }
?>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am unable to execute this query?

Comment: use mysql_error() to find whats wrong

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: Can you put `mysql_error()` to your `else` ?

Comment: If that is the start of your code, you have not connected to the database.

Comment: `echo'<font color="red"> Error : '.mysql_error().'</font>';`

Comment: `query does not run` is the message `you` show. use `mysql_error()` to show what's wrong

Comment: This is a horrible piece of code! Besides, what happens if `mysql_num_rows` returns 0?

Comment: Why use a `while` if you know there's only one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It doesn't appear that you are connecting to any database.

2) You're using `mysql_` functions which are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql) and leave you open to SQL injection. You should immediately stop using it to write new code and use `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions.

3) You need to append `mysql_error()` to catch any possible errors. Perhaps something like this:

```
...
} else {
    mysql_error();
    }
```

4) It is poor practice to `SELECT *`. You should always specify a column list.

Comment: About your point 3, Why do you need to use double quotes when echoing html code ?

Comment: 2, 5 are nice tips, but neither address the problem. 3 is no problem, since there are no variables. 4. mysql_error doesn't catch errors (you can do that by checking the result of mysql_query), although it helps to find out *what* the error is. Let's hope it's 1. :)

Comment: If you want your variables to be interpolated, you need to use double quotes. Otherwise doesn't matter. Also point 2 needs emphasis on *immediately* as in **step away** from `mysql_query`.

Comment: @tadman Yes, in fact I tend to use single quotes when not interpolating variables.

Comment: You still are wrong about your point 3

Comment: None of your points illustrate what exactly is wrong with the code.

Comment: Apologies on point 3, it's been removed. Was getting confused with variables.

Comment: Another thing to add is using an ORM like [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org/) to help clean up the database calls and make writing them less of an issue.

Answer (score -1):

SQL single-Quotes

```
$query="SELECT * FROM `banner_ad` WHERE `banner_no`='$sn'";
```

Change to PHP single-Quotes

```
$query="SELECT * FROM 'banner_ad' WHERE 'banner_no'='$sn'";
```

Comment: -1. Single quotes, inside SQL queries, denote string literals. Your suggestion will make the query fail because of syntax errors.